# AWS Amazon Polly mp3 file creation through java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-polly

I have a requirement to create text to speech component using AEM(Java) and i am using Amazon polly for that.
I need to AWS library with SDK 2.0 version. I am sending the text in the request and directly saving the mp3 file into the AWS S3 bucket and in return i need the url of the mp3 file.
I am unable to find any example where polly is used to create mp3 file and is directly getting stored over S3 bucket.
Anyone who can provide me the example to do it through java?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/SynthesizeSpeechSample.html)

```
package com.amazonaws.polly.samples;

import com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPolly;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPollyClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.OutputFormat;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.SynthesizeSpeechRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.SynthesizeSpeechResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.VoiceId;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class SynthesizeSpeechSample {
    AmazonPolly client = AmazonPollyClientBuilder.defaultClient();

    public void synthesizeSpeech() {
        String outputFileName = "/tmp/speech.mp3";

        SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthesizeSpeechRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest()
                .withOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mp3)
                .withVoiceId(VoiceId.Joanna)
                .withText("This is a sample text to be synthesized.");

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName))) {
            SynthesizeSpeechResult synthesizeSpeechResult = client.synthesizeSpeech(synthesizeSpeechRequest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2 * 1024];
            int readBytes;

            try (InputStream in = synthesizeSpeechResult.getAudioStream()){
                while ((readBytes = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception caught: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```